# Service Connection Point and SP1

Tags: cumulative-update, service-pack

First time installing SP1 on my test farm and started off installing foundation SP1 first, rebooted and then ran "psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait" to finish the upgrade.

During this run of the configuration wizard it completed 3 of the 4 stages at 100% but errored out on the final stage prompting me to look through the logs to find the issue,correct it and re-run config wizard.

I looked through the logs and found this reference: " Creating service connection point for this farm ...
05/12/2012 22:04:14  4  WRN            Failed to add the service connection point for this farm
05/12/2012 22:04:14  4  INF            Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/12/2012 22:04:14  4  INF              Resource id to be retrieved is ServiceConnectionPointNotCreatedEventLog for language English (United States)
05/12/2012 22:04:14  4  INF              Resource retrieved id ServiceConnectionPointNotCreatedEventLog is Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
05/12/2012 22:04:14  4  INF            Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
05/12/2012 22:04:14  4  WRN            Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=contoso,DC=com doesn't exist in the directory.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
05/12/2012 22:05:42  4  INF            Entering function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
05/12/2012 22:05:42  4  INF              Not spawing off the upgrade job, but rather running upgrade synchronously by calling SPFarm.Local.Upgrade() for inplace upgrade
05/12/2012 22:05:42  4  INF            Leaving function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
05/12/2012 22:13:31  4  ERR            Task upgrade has failed with an unknown exception 
05/12/2012 22:13:31  4  ERR            Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Upgrade completed with errors.  Review the upgrade log file located in D:\SPLogs\TraceLogs\Upgrade-20120512-220230-65.log.  The number of errors and warnings is listed at the end of the upgrade log file.

I did some digging around to figure out what this connection Point is...apparently it's disabled by defualt if you never make the container but some people have reported the same problem as me...am i forced to create this container just to satisfy this issue?

Or can i just ignore the error and assume my update completed correctly?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this a common issue. I had same issue after researching why Search wasn't working and only returning an error message. You could fix the issue by following instructions here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/04/18/track-sharepoint-2010-installations-by-service-connection-point-ad-marker.aspx 
But, you don't want to leave as is. You can run the psconfig update again (PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures) and update will succeed even without the fix above. It seems that the second run has only the permanent feature install lines (mine was reporting services feature) and must have removed the other features. I am doing this on workspace (free) edition, and my search is working again. I did have to do an IISReset.